# Normalize a histogram and make the scale log linear simultaneously,

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have data in list b3, First step is normalizing the histogram using the following command,
Histogram[b3, 100, "ProbabilityDensity"]

Second I would like to make the y scale log, I use

Histogram[b3, 1000, "ProbabilityDensity", "LogCount"]

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
b3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];
```

Use the form `{"Log", hspec}` in the third argument of `Histogram` to get log transformed heights (see [`Histogram >> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)):

```
Histogram[b3, 100, {"Log", "PDF"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the option [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html):

```
Histogram[b3, 100, "PDF", ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]
```

[image]

**Note:** Height specification `"ProbabilityDensity"` (afaik) is not documented and it gives the same height list as `"PDF"`:

```
HistogramList[b3, 100, "PDF"][[2]] == 
 HistogramList[b3, 100, "ProbabilityDensity"][[2]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
HistogramList[b3, 100, {"Log", "PDF"}][[2]] == 
 HistogramList[b3, 100, {"Log", "ProbabilityDensity"}][[2]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thank a lot, it is very helpful.

Comment: @SachinKaushik, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: If i further want to divide y axis by 2 then how can i include it. Question is i have data, first step is obtaining normalized histogram which you showed and then divide the y axis of histogram by 2, keeping everything else same.

Comment: @SachinKaushik, you can use something like: `hl = HistogramList[b3, 100, "PDF"];
Histogram[b3, {hl[[1]]}, hl[[2]]/2 &,  ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]`